# Add border on hover in Map area using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a map area and I want to add border when hover each area.

```
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
      <area shape="rect" coords="350,2521,479,2592" href="http://www.iba.org.il/" target="_blank" class="tooltip-blue" data-tooltip-position="left" data-tooltip="?? ???????? ?? ????? ?????? ??????." data-hasqtip="87">
      <area shape="rect" coords="625,454,760,523" href="http://easyvie.yolasite.com/#meas" class="tooltip-red" data-tooltip-position="left" data-tooltip="More info" data-hasqtip="88">
</map>
```

Please help.

Comment: What is it supposed to be?

Comment: Is there a reason to use jQuery rather than CSS?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("area").hover(function(){
    $("area").css("border","3px solid #000");//onhover code
    },function(){//mouse out code
    $("area").css("border","none");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ...

```
<style>
.tooltip-blue:hover {
     border: 1px solid blue;
}
</style>
```

Everything inside the style tags can be placed in CSS.